# Access the field of an object in a Linked List - C#

Tags: c#, linked-list

I want to find all the objects in a Linked List which satisfy a certain requirement. Their internal state (one field) must assume a specific value.

Consider these three classes (I will give only essential information):

```
public class Notification
{
    public DateTime timeStamp { get; private set; }

    public uint sourceApp { get; private set; }

    public int [,,] icon { get; private set; }


}

public class PearStack
{
    public LinkedList<Notification> notifications { get; private set; }
   //...
}

public class NotificationDispatcher
{
    public PearStack[] pearStacks { get; private set; }

    public NotificationDispatcher(uint s, PearStack pearstack)
    {
       //...
    }
    //...
}
```

In the constructor "NotificationDispatcher" I have as input a "PearStack" object and an integer.

A PearStack object (pearstack) has a linked list of Notifications.

I want to select all the objects (Notifications) of the linked list contained in pearstack which have the field "sourceapp" equal to "s".

I thought about:

```
pearstack.notifications.Find(s)
```

But it is wrong.

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can do this with a simple LINQ query:

```
var notificationsForApp = pearstack.notifications.Where(x => x.sourceApp == s);
```

This will give you an `IEnumerable<Notification>` where enumerating will only give you the notifications matching the source app. To enumerate immediately and get a `List<Notification>` or `Notification[]`, simply append `ToList()` or `ToArray()` to the end of the statement.

Comment: Keep in mind that this does _not_ have optimum performance. If performance is a concern here, use a `foreach` loop over pearstack.notifications and add the ones you want to a list.